# How can i use php code inside wordpress textarea?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, textarea, echo

I want to use the following code inside the Wordpress textarea :

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "embed", true)):

echo  ' ';

endif;
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: use php block, <?php  //your code ?>

Comment: Are you trying to use php inside admin  editor?

Comment: Why is it tagged jQuery ?

Comment: Yes i want to put php code inside admin new post text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What textarea is it exactly?
The one from writing a new article?

If you're trying to use it there you could define your php as a shortcode in your functions.php and use the shortcode in the textarea afterwards.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

And I guess there are plugins to execute php in articles but I don't think it's recommendable.

Comment: Yes i want to put the php inside writing a new article textarea,why its not recommendable ?

Comment: can you give me one plugin name please ?

Comment: There's two big reasons not to do this. The first, and most important, is that adding the ability to execute PHP in a post body makes it possible for anyone (whether it's you, another user, or someone who hacked into your site) to execute code. It's a security risk, opening the door to additional modifications you might never even know about. In a similar vein, a lot of security-conscious people suggest disabling the built-in plugin & theme editors.

Comment: The other big reason is that PHP code you enter this way is code you can't keep in a version control system or easily search. It's separate from all the other code on your site. It's not even in the filesystem.

Comment: Well yes, those are the reasons :) Thanks for commenting.
Like I said it would be fine to use shortcodes. Also you can reuse those whenever you want. Here's two plugins that migh help you nevertheless:    
http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/    http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/

Comment: but those plugins use shorcode inside textare  is this safer ?

Comment: the reason i want it is because i have  a rollover tab plugin and i want to put 
 if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "embedcode", true)):
echo  '<input type="button"  value="play" onclick="showDiv2()">';
endif; and i want to show this button inside a play tab on the rollover tab plugin. the plugin uses shortcode and i created a shortcode for that php echo but when i put shortcode inside the tab shortcode i see the button outside that tab and even if i dont click the tab... can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal php syntax for this
`<?php //....code....  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

For PHP in TXT widgets :

```
    function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}

add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
```

Inside the Editor, just use normal php code ( `<?php //my_code ?>` ) but make sure you are in `text mode` not `visual mode`

Comment: i don't want to put php on widgets, but in new post text area. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: SO like i said , just put the code inside , and make sure that you are in the `text-mode` and not the `visual-mode`

Comment: i tried it and it doesnt work. visual and text mode . both doesn't works